Is it possible to instruct XTerm to use two specific weights for the regular font and the bold faces?

Yellow XTerm from xterm -fa 'Cascadia SemiBold'
Pink XTerm from xterm -fa Cascadia
As you can see, when I use Cascadia SemiBold the text is slightly heavier but the headers are rendered with the same weight, while in the other XTerm, using plain Cascadia, the headers are rendered with, I think so because it's heavier than Semibold, Cascadia Bold.
If it is possible to instruct XTerm to use two specific weights for the regular font and the bold faces, I was unable to find the solution in its man page.
Is it possible to instruct XTerm to use two specific weights for the regular font and the bold faces?

Addendum
Pink is "regular" Cascadia, yellow is "Cascadia Code ExtraLight" and here XTerm was able to deduce a proper bold face. It's a little bit puzzling…


Not easily: xterm gets the normal, bold and italic variations using the same family pattern.  You'd only see differences in the family if one of those variations was supplied by a fallback font rather than the specified family.

@ThomasDickey E.g., XTerm can find one of those variations when tha primary face is "Cascadia Code ExtraLight"
